# Are facebook App ID and App Secret specific for every user that uses facebook connect

Tags: facebook, servlets, jsf-2

Hi all i have a problem with facebook connect, i'm using these API to make users login to my web application using their facebook account, as a previous step i get an App ID and APP Secret from [developers.facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/), the problem is that the login doesn't authenticate any account except the one that i use it when i make the App ID and the App secret, please help me in understanding these issue

Note: i use these [tutorials](http://www.adfkickstart.com/facebook-user-authentication-in-java-web-application) to integrate my web application with facebook connect

for more clarity, this is the start jsf page (the source code is available in the link mentioned in my post):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Login Page</h1>
    <h:form id="loginForm">
        <p:button value="Facebook Connect" href="#{loginPageCode.facebookUrlAuth}" />
        <br/><br/>
        <h:outputText value="#{loginPageCode.userFromSession}"></h:outputText>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

and this is the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "loginPageCode")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginPageCode implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1611162265998907599L;

public String getFacebookUrlAuth() {
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    String sessionId = session.getId();
    String appId = "3827326728372872";
    String redirectUrl  = "http://localhost:8080/Test/index.sec";
    String returnValue = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
            + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUrl
            + "&scope=email,user_birthday&state=" + sessionId;
    System.out.println("Return Value---->"+returnValue);
    return returnValue;
}

public String getUserFromSession() {
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("FACEBOOK_USER");
    System.out.println("FACEBOOK_USER-->"+userName);
    if (userName != null) {
        return "Hello " + userName;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in your title -
No, the application id and secret are the same for any user.

The issue here (I assume) is that your application is in sandbox mode. Disable that mode and everything should work.

Sandbox mode is for use during development of the application and only the users that are listed in the "roles" section of the application settings will be able to access the application.

Comment: i disabled the sandbox mode and it still insists to authenticate only the account that i used to make an App ID !! i'm really astonished

Comment: @jav - issues when only certain *users* can't perform tasks is usually related to the sandbox mode setting. The only other issue I could imagine is that you have an error in your code; But that doesn't sound likely as you say it *does* work for the account that created the application. Could you perhaps add to your question above some relevant code that deals with the auth process?

Comment: i'm using the application in the tutorial mentioned in my post

Comment: Your server is local on your computer? Can the other users reach your server?

Comment: No, i just have their usernames and passwords to test the applications

Comment: Are you using the [proper test users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/)?

Comment: i'm testing the application using normal users because the application is supposed to be used with any user when it's deployed

Comment: I understand that - what I'm saying is that there is no other way to prevent users from authenticating unless you explicitly disallow them in your code. Are those users able to authenticate any application? I urge you to use the test users - this really is the best way to test with the least amount of noise.

Comment: Ok, but i have been trying many normal accounts, and i'm sure these accounts aren't disabled from authenticating any application, and i prefer to test the app using normal accounts

Comment: it seems to be that you have to wait a period of minutes for the sandbox disable to take, effect, it works now, the problem was in the sandbox as you said, thanks Lix

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it sorted itself out. It's good to know that these things can take some time to kick in...